# Java code executing command with Powershell 3 returning question marks despite setting codepage and outputEncoding.

Tags: java, utf-8, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This is regarding a problem for which, I have done fair amount of research but could not find an answer that works for me. Hence posting a new question.

**Summary**
Executing powershell command with java code and **powershell 3** is not returning `UTF-8 characters`. Same thing works when I execute same command with **java code and powershell version 2**.

**Scenario**:
I have a java code which is starting a new process and executing the powershell script.
At the end, is the complete java file and the powershell script where I am setting the codepage and outputEncoding so that I can get output in UTF-8.
Below is the java code snippet which is not giving expected results:

```
//String command = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned \"C:\\temp\\ListDirectory.ps1\"";
String command = "powershell.exe -Version 2.0 -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned \"C:\\temp\\ListDirectory.ps1\"";
Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
String line;

System.out.println("Standard Output:");
//PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
//CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();

BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
stdout.close();
```

Now problem is, this code works fine when I run this with `powershell version 2.0` explicitly and gives the expected output (i.e. displaying UTF-8 characters, here snowman character):

```
C:\temp\Snowman☃folder\snowman☃file
```

But when I uncomment first line (to use latest version of powershell) and run the java code, it returns me `?` for snowman characters. Here is the output:

```
C:\temp\Snowman?folder\snowman?file
```

I tried various options like

- Setting the envp while starting java process but it didnt work
- Setting charDecoder, but it didnt work
- Setting charset as "UTF-8", but it didnt work
- I also tried to pipe the output to a file and surprisingly, the file content had the UTF-8 characters. I cant understand why its not working while getting the output in Java.

Kindly suggest what am I missing or something which I should explore.
Thanks in advance.

**Here is the Complete Java code**

​    public class PowershellUtil {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    invokePowershell();
    //printString();
}

static void printString() throws IOException {
    String snowman = "Ê ☃ é";
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    out.println(snowman);
}

static void invokePowershell() throws IOException {

    // String command = "powershell.exe your command";
    // Getting the version
    // String command = "powershell.exe  $PSVersionTable";
    //String command = "powershell.exe -Version 2.0 Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\\temp\\Snowman☃folder' -Recurse -Filter 'snowman☃file' | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}";
    //String command = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned \"C:\\temp\\ListDirectory.ps1\"";
    String command = "powershell.exe -Version 2.0 -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned \"C:\\temp\\ListDirectory.ps1\"";

    // Executing the command
    /*String[] envp = { "file.encoding=UTF8" };
    Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, envp);*/
    Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Getting the results
    powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
    String line;
    System.out.println("Standard Output:");
    //PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    //CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();

    BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    stdout.close();
    /*InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream());
    int data = isr.read();
    while (data != -1) {
        char theChar = (char) data;
        System.out.println("read character: " + String.valueOf(theChar));
        data = isr.read();
    }
    isr.close();*/

    System.out.println("Standard Error:");
    BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
    while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    stderr.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

}​

**Here is the powershell script**

```
Set-Variable UTF8_CODEPAGE 65001
Set-Variable UTF8_ENCODING "System.Text.UTF8Encoding"
chcp $UTF8_CODEPAGE > $null
$OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename $UTF8_ENCODING
# $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
# Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\temp\Snowman☃folder' -Recurse -Filter 'snowman☃file' | ForEach-Object FullName | Out-File 'C:\temp\result.txt'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\temp\Snowman☃folder' -Recurse -Filter 'snowman☃file' | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}
# Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\result.txt" -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` before printing the output.

Comment: Phew...I did notice this and used in different configuration (System.text.UTF8Encoding) but it didnt work at that time. But now, it worked. Thanks a lot. It did save me lot of time.